# CodeChef TurboSort (Sorting using int vs Integer )

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

> Given the list of numbers, you are to sort them in non decreasing
>   order. Input
>
> t – the number of numbers in list, then t lines follow [t <= 10^6]. 
>   Each line contains one integer: N [0 <= N <= 10^6] Output
>
> Output given numbers in non decreasing order. Example
>
> Input: 5 5 3 6 7 1 Output: 1 3 5 6 7

***First implementation using literal int values and using the Arrays.sort() function that sorts the literals using the Quicksort Algo ( worst case n^2 , average case - nlogn )***

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    InputStream inputStream = System.in;
    OutputStream outputStream = System.out;
    InputReader in = new InputReader(inputStream);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream);

    int num = in.nextInt();

    int[] n = new int[num];

    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {

      n[i] = in.nextInt();

    }

    Arrays.sort(n);


    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) out.println(n[i]);


    out.close();

  }
}


class InputReader {
  private BufferedReader reader;
  private StringTokenizer tokenizer;

  public InputReader(InputStream stream) {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    tokenizer = null;
  }

  public String next() {
    while (tokenizer == null || !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
      try {
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
    return tokenizer.nextToken();
  }

  public int nextInt() {
    return Integer.parseInt(next());
  }

}
```

**The next implementation is storing and sorting the int literals as Integer objects and using the Arrays.sort() method that now sorts the Integer objects using the MergeSort algo that guarantees nlogn performance**

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.InputStream;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream inputStream = System.in;
    OutputStream outputStream = System.out;
    InputReader in = new InputReader(inputStream);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
    int T = in.nextInt();

    Integer[] ARR = new Integer[T];

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) ARR[i] = in.nextInt();

    Arrays.sort(ARR);

    for (int i : ARR) out.println(i);

    out.close();
  }

}

class InputReader {
  private BufferedReader reader;
  private StringTokenizer tokenizer;

  public InputReader(InputStream stream) {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    tokenizer = null;
  }

  public String next() {
    while (tokenizer == null || !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
      try {
        tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
    return tokenizer.nextToken();
  }

  public int nextInt() {
    return Integer.parseInt(next());
  }

}
```

However the issue now is that as per logic, the mergesort algo ( i.e the Integer object sorting implementation ) should take less or equal time with respect to the Quicksort algo ) i.e the int literal sorting implementation is taking lesser time ...

*Integer Object sorting implementation - 0.94sec
int literal sorting implementation - 0.53sec*

**Am i missing something ?
what is the reason for this excess time ? 
is it because of autoboxing and autounboxing ?!is that the reason for this excess time ...**

Comment: btw as you know that your elements are ints and < 10 ^6, you can sort them with linear complexity.

Comment: Probably because you're not measuring what you think you are measuring. You're probably measuring HotSpot compilation times, JVM startup times, your disk throughput, etc. Read this post first and then post your new benchmark results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like you thank you for reminding me that i had codechef account which i had dumped long back.Here is the solution i did at that time it took me .20 seconds to run The code is little bit big Hope you find this useful thanks..

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

class Reader
{
    private static final int  BUFSIZE   = 0x10000;
    private final byte[]      buffer    = new byte[BUFSIZE];
    private final ByteBuffer  bb        = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
    private final FileChannel channel;

    int                       bufSize   = -1;                     // non empty buffer
    int                       bufOffset = 0;                      // non valid buffer

    private FileInputStream getFileInputStream(InputStream in)
    {
        try
        {
            if (in instanceof BufferedInputStream)
            {
                Field field = in.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("in");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                return (FileInputStream) field.get(in);
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return (FileInputStream) in;
    }

    Reader(InputStream in) throws IOException
    {
        this.channel = this.getFileInputStream(in).getChannel();
    }

    void fetchBuffer() throws IOException
    {
        bb.clear();
        bufSize = channel.read(bb);
        bufOffset = 0;
    }

    boolean isFinished()
    {
        return bufSize <= 0;
    }

    private int peek() throws IOException
    {
        if (bufOffset < bufSize)
            return buffer[bufOffset];
        fetchBuffer();
        if (bufSize > 0)
            return buffer[0];
        return -1;
    }

    private void skipSpace() throws IOException
    {
        int v = peek();
        while (v <= ' ' && v != -1)
        {
            bufOffset++;
            v = peek();
        }
    }

    void nextLine() throws IOException
    {
        int v = peek();
        while (v != -1 && v != '\n' && v != '\r')
        {
            bufOffset++;
            v = peek();
        }
        if (v == '\r')
        {
            bufOffset++;
            v = peek();
            if (v == '\n')
                bufOffset++;
        }
        else if (v == '\n')
        {
            bufOffset++;
            v = peek();
            if (v == '\r')
                bufOffset++;
        }
    }

    int readInt() throws IOException
    {
        skipSpace();
        int result = 0;
        int v = peek();
        while (v > ' ')
        {
            result = result * 10 + v - '0';
            bufOffset++;
            v = peek();
        }
        return result;
    }

}

class Writer
{
    private static final int       BUFSIZE = 0x10000;
    private final FileOutputStream fos;
    private final byte[]           buffer  = new byte[BUFSIZE];
    private int                    offset  = 0;

    private FileOutputStream getFileOutputStream(PrintStream out)
    {
        try
        {
            Field field = out.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("out");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            OutputStream os = (OutputStream) field.get(out);
            if (os instanceof BufferedOutputStream)
            {
                BufferedOutputStream bos = (BufferedOutputStream) os;
                field = bos.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("out");
                field.setAccessible(true);
                return (FileOutputStream) field.get(bos);
            }
            return (FileOutputStream) field.get(out);
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    Writer(PrintStream out) throws IOException
    {
        fos = getFileOutputStream(out);
    }

    private static final int[]  boundaries = new int[]
    {
        9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999, 999999, 9999999,
        99999999, 999999999
    };
    private static final int[]  divs       = new int[]
    {
        1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000,
        10000000, 100000000
    };
    private static final byte[] numbers    = "0123456789".getBytes();

    void writeln(int number) throws IOException
    {
        if (offset > BUFSIZE - 100)
            flush();
        int index;
        for (index = 0; index < boundaries.length; index++)
            if (number <= boundaries[index])
                break;
        for (; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            int mult = number / divs[index];
            buffer[offset++] = numbers[mult];
            number -= mult * divs[index];
        }
        buffer[offset++] = '\n';
    }

    void flush() throws IOException
    {
        if (offset > 0)
        {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, offset);
            offset = 0;
        }
    }
}



class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Reader r=new Reader(System.in);
        Writer w=new Writer(System.out);

        int x,k;
        int[] arr2 = new int[1000000];
        x = r.readInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            arr2[r.readInt()]++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {

                 k= arr2[i];
               while(k-- > 0){
                   w.writeln(i);
               }


        }
        w.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Integer is of object and it usually takes long time to process.

Comment: wow... this is abstract to the point of being unreadable  .. (i'm  a novice ) so, it would be kind of you if you could explain as to what is happening here ..... else i will just resort to random googling as always and hope i get an understanding of this code .. Thanks !

Comment: @Vonn The first part is only used to read the input data. You don't need to understand it (and you would not implement it like this nowadays). Just read the `Solution` class. For more information, you can google about "counting sort algorithm".

Answer (score 1):

For starters, both merge sort and quick sort in practice have similar performance. In fact, quick sort typically outperforms it with random data slightly. But even if merge sort were slightly better, sorting Integers are always going to be significantly slower because sorting objects are tougher than primitives. They don't work with your cache as well as primitives.

Answer (score 1):

The sorting takes longer mainly because with Integer, you are storing an object, which is a lot of overhead.